# Adding samples on the same figure with out deleting the previous samples using bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to plot large data in one graph sample by sample. The newly sampled data should be added to the previous samples on the same plot. I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work as intended. It only displays the current sample; it does not display all the previous samples. Any idea how to do it using bokeh?

```
import numpy as np
import time
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.session import Session
from random import randint
from bokeh.objects import GLyph,GridPlot, HoverTool  

output_notebook(url="default")
#output_notebook()

figure(x_range=[0,1000000],y_range=[0,100],plot_width=1000,plot_height=600,title="Hello World!")
hold()
xs = []
ys = []
x = []
y = []
for num in range(0,1000000):
    xs.append(num)
for num in range(0,1000000):
    ys.append(randint(0,100))
scatter(x, y, color='#33A02C', fill_color=None, size=8)
renderer = [r for r in curplot().renderers if isinstance(r, Glyph)][0]
ds = renderer.data_source
show()
i = 0
iteration = 0
last = len(xs)
sampleSize = 1000
while(iteration <= len(xs)/sampleSize):
    x = xs[i:i+sampleSize]
    y = ys[i:i+sampleSize]
    ds.data["x"] = x
    ds.data["y"] = y
    ds._dirty = True
    cursession().store_objects(ds)
    iteration = iteration + 1
    i = i + sampleSize
```